# Oracle database validate password of user

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am looking to validate a database user with a procedure. I need to check to see if a password given by a user is the password for this user and then return a boolean. I know I can use the **alter user** command with the option **replace**, but this will actually alter the user's password which will be logged as a password change on the back-end. I need to avoid this and simply validate if the password is correct. Is there any methods to do this?

Answer (score 0):

pelas take a look at [How to validate my password with the value in the oracle database and also what is the difference between return 0 and return 1 in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880728/how-to-validate-my-password-with-the-value-in-the-oracle-database-and-also-what)

```
                               `
    public int present(){

     // make query for Oracle data base
         String yourQry = "select * from yourtable where password = '"+pass+"' and username='"+username+"'" . 
      //Use this query when you are fetching data from user.
      Resultset rs;     // fetch your data in resultset
           if(rs.next()){
                 // if data got fetched 
                 return 1;
                 // 1 means true
            }
           else{
                    return 0; // 0 means false (No datafound) 
           }

          } `
```